# Bootstrap carousel - style pagination dots

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 carousel that has 3 images with white background. My pagination dots are lost now, given that they have a white border with a transparent center (in my case, white as well). How can I use CSS to style these to a darker color? Thanks in advance!

Here's my carousel inner (pretty standard):

```
   <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
       <img src="images/img1.png" alt="img1">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3>...</h3>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="item">
       <img src="images/img2.png" alt="img2">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3>...</h3>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="item">
       <img src="images/img3.png" alt="img3">
       <br>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3>...</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the markup you provided, I don't see the indicators. Make sure that you have the following markup present in your slideshow.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

To change the indicator colors you will need to change it in two different places. The first is the general indicator color which will change all of them. The second is the color of the indicator for the active slide.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    background: #ccc;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #666;
}
```

Comment: Ah I didn't realize those were the indicators I was looking for. I do have them, but they aren't in `carousel-inner`. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you.